# C++: storing a matrix in a 1D array

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++, but I have the task of translating a section of C++ code into python.

Going through the file, I found this section of code, which confuses me:

```
int n_a=(e.g 10)

int n_b=n_a-1;
int l_b[2*n_b];
int l_c[3*n_b];
int l_d[4*n_b];
for (int i=0; i<n_b; i++){ 
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) l_b[i*2+j]=0;  
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) l_c[i*3+j]=0; 
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) l_d[i*4+j]=0;
```

I know that it creates 3 arrays, the length of each defined by the action on the n_b variable, and sets all the elements to zero, but I do not understand what exactly this matrix is supposed to look like, e.g. if written on paper.

Comment: I would guess that `l_b` is either a matrix of `n_b` rows and 2 columns, or 2 rows and `n_b` columns. which can also be interpreted as a vector (in the mathematical sense, not `std::vector`) of 2-vectors. But without knowing what the data represents, it's impossible to say for sure. You probably want to use `numpy` for the translation and not use explicit loops like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to store a matrix with `R` rows and `C` columns is to store all elements in a vector of size `R * C`. Then when you need element `(i, j)` you just index the vector with `i*C + j`. This is not the only way your "matrix" could be stored in memory, but it is a common one.

In this code there are 3 C arrays that declared and initialized with zeros. The `l_b` array seems to be storage for a `n_a x 2` matrix, the `l_c` array for a `n_a x 3` matrix and the `l_d` array for a `n_a x 4` matrix.

Of course, this is only an impression since to be sure we would need to see how these arrays are used later.

As in the comments, if you are going to convert this to python then you should probably use numpy for the matrices. In fact, the numpy arrays will store the elements in memory exactly like indexing I mentioned (by default, but you can also choose an alternative way passing an extra argument). You could do the same of this C++ code in oython with just

```py
import numpy as np

n_a = (e.g 10)

l_b = np.zeros(shape=(n_a, 2))
l_c = np.zeros(shape=(n_a, 3))
l_d = np.zeros(shape=(n_a, 4))
```

These variables in numpy are 2D arrays and you can index them as usual.
Ex:

```
l_d[2, 1] = 15.5
```

---

We can also have a nice syntax for working with vector, matrices and linear algebra in C++ by using one of the available libraries. One such library is [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). We can create the three previous matrices of zeros using armadillo as

```cpp
#include <armadillo>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int n_a = 10;

    // A 10 x 3 matrix of doubles with all elements being zero
    // The 'arma::fill::zeros' argument is optional and without it the matrix
    // elements will not be initialized
    arma::mat l_b(n_a, 2, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::mat l_c(n_a, 3, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::mat l_d(n_a, 4, arma::fill::zeros);

    // We use parenthesis for index, since "[]" can only receive one element in C/C++
    l_b(2, 1) = 15.5;

    // A nice function for printing, but it also works with operator<<
    l_b.print("The 'l_b' matrix is");

    return 0;
}
```

If you inspect armadillo types in gdb you will see that it has a `mem` atribute which is a pointer. This is in fact a C array for the internal elements of the matrix and when you index the matrix in armadillo it will translate the indexes into the proper index in this internal 1D array.

You can print the elements in this internal arry in gdb. For instance, `print l_b.mem[0]` will print the first element, `print l_b.mem[1]` will print the second element, and so one.

Comment: Yes of course, numpy is a much better system for building matrices, the problem for me was that the code obfuscated what the matrices looked like. Could you clarify your initial statement a little for me? By 'stored in vector' you mean all the elements are stored in a 1D array? And in this code there appear to be 3 such arrays used as matrices.

Comment: Yes, all elements are stored internally as a 1D array. Numpy stores all elements in a in a 1D array (array in the C sense) no matter how many dimensions the numpy "array" (array in numpy sense, which can have multiple dimensions) has. When you index the multidimensional array numpy it translates the multidimensional indexes for you to get the requested element(s). That is why operations such as transpose or reshape are very quick. They just change how the index if done without touching the elements. There are also libraries for matrices and linear algebra in C++ and they do something similar.

Comment: @darcamo A connected question plz. How would you avoid hard coding the row and col dimension of an armadillo matrix during initialization in C++? This question in details may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868123/dynamic-parameterization-of-armadillo-matrix-dimensions-in-c